# Converting from a char * to a char[31] in C

Tags: c, list, pointers, struct

I have a struct called symbolEntry that contains a char[31] variable called "name." I have a function in which I pass a char *, in essence a string, and try to assign it to the symbolEntry's name value. However, I come up with the following error.

symList.c:19: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[31]’ from type ‘char *’

I have tried creating a temporary variable a[31] and using a strncopy to copy the passed string, but I keep getting this same error. Any ideas?

Here's my code:

```
typedef struct symbolEntry
{
    char type;
    char name[31];
    struct symbolEntry * next;
} symbolEntry;

void insertN(symbolEntry ** first, char * symbolName, char type)
{
    symbolEntry * entry = (symbolEntry *)malloc(sizeof(symbolEntry));
    entry->type = type;
    char a[31];
    strncpy(a, symbolName, 31);
    entry->name = a;
    entry->next = *first;
    first = &entry;
}
```

Comment: strncpy(entry->name,symbolName,30); entry->name[31]='\0';

Comment: And you probably want *first=entry;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to create a temporary array. Just use `strncpy` to copy directly into the struct's `name` field.

Comment: Suggest `entry->name[31-1] = '\0';` after the `strncpy();`